# return after navigation.navigate() in component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

`react-navigation 3.9.1` is used in my react native 0.59 app. I notice that the code after `this.props.navigation.navigate()` will be executed after sometime. Here is any example:

```
async componentDidMount(){
      console.log('Did mount event');

      try {
        //retrieving token
        const result = await helper.getJwtToken();
        console.log("secure store : ", result);
        if (!result) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup");
          return;  //<<<=== added to prevent the code below from being executed
        };

        let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/events/active?_device_id=${encodeURIComponent(DeviceInfo.getUniqueID())}`;
        console.log("event url : ", url);
        .........
```

Without `return`, the code after `this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup");` will be executed eventually after certain time which interrupts the flow. I am not sure if this `return` is pro pattern. Is there a better way to handle after navigation?

Comment: Why not `else`?

Comment: or after this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup"); .  this.componentWillUnmount();

Comment: The situation is !result is `true` and this.props.navigation.navigate() is executed. The code after `if` handles the else.